# Cannot change upload_max_filesize or post_max_size in php.ini

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, php, ec2-ami

Bear in mind, I am no sysadmin, I am just a developer. I cannot find anyone with the *exact* problem as me, just similar, and none of their "fixes" seem to work.

I am currently running an Amazon EC2 instance running.

```
CentOS 6.2
Nginx 1.2.2
PHP 5.3.16 with APC
Percona 5.5.24 // not currently using this as I am using an RDS
```

I have set my php.ini (/etc/php.ini) settings to the following

```
upload_max_filesize=10M
post_max_filesize=20M
```

After reloading the config, using `php -i` via ssh, these settings seemed to be loaded. Showing `upload_max_filesize=10M`, etc.

When using `phpinfo()` or `ini_get`, both options are returned as `4M`

`phpinfo()` indicates that the file I am editing is the one loaded (`/etc/php.ini`).

I have also run `php -i | grep "\.ini"` to check which files are loaded, and there are no unnecessary loaded configs. I even went through each loaded file individually to check they didn't have the settings inside.

Additionally, I have been suggested to try using a `.user.ini` config file. This did not change the values either.

`ini_set()` does not work either.

I'm at a bit of a loss.

EDIT: not sure this will help, but I am using this AMI http://megumi-cloud.com/

Comment: what is your real problem?are you trying to upload the files through any interface form or what?

Comment: Tell more about your PHP SAPI. `.user.ini` is for CGI/FCGI instances. In Apache you were to use `.htaccess` alternatively. PHP5.3.3+ seemingly provides a environment variable workaround for nginx: http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,22556,99839#msg-99839

Comment: It's just a basic image upload script, for avatars, but the default upload amount it too low. The server is running fpm-fcgi. I did try `.htaccess` file, but for obvious reasons, it did nothing.

Comment: @sivann I am not sure, as it was using a preconfigured AMI from the amazon community section when creating a new instance. Checking its version just returns the php version, `5.3.16`. Is there a way to check?

Comment: @sivann Oh, I misunderstood. `CentOS release 6.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got in contact with the guys who made the AMI and found out there are additional configuration files that override the `php.ini`

There are 2 files which hold settings

```
/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf // This is the file which holds upload_max_filesize and post_max_size, among others
/etc/php-fpm.conf
```

Obviously the locations may differ on different configurations, but hopefully this will help give someone an idea of what else to look for.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and edited the `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` file by increasing `upload_max_filesize = 10M`. I then had to `sudo service php5-fpm restart` & `sudo service nginx restart` for it to finally work (this was on Ubuntu 12.04 though).

Comment: Doing `sudo service php5-fpm restart` and `sudo service nginx restart` worked for me where `sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart` and `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart` didn't!

Comment: This! `sudo service php-fpm restart` and `sudo service nginx restart` in my case

Answer (score 17):

Filename:

```
nginx/sites-available/default
```

Add:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 50M \n post_max_size=51M";
}
```

Run:
From command line: `sudo service nginx restart`

Answer (score 7):

Try to do a command like this:

```
php --ini
```

It will show you which ini files are loaded by php.

Example output:

```
[admin@staging ~]$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/extensions.ini
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you explicitly set those values in your php.ini file and they are not the same when you run your PHP script, then something has overridden them. You know your php.ini settings are correct because the CLI version of PHP info shows the new settings.

> I have also run php -i | grep ".ini" to check which files are loaded, and there are no unnecessary loaded configs. I even went through each loaded file individually to check they didn't have the settings inside.

This is great, but it's telling you what .ini files have been loaded from the PHP CLI---not your application.

You need to check the *Additional .ini files parsed* section of your `phpinfo()` output to see exactly what files are being loaded from your web server. One of those files is overriding your settings.

Finally, if none of those files turn out to be the culprit, you should do a global find on `ini_set()` in your project to make sure some rogue script isn't setting those values for you (trying to be *helpful*).

Keep digging, you'll find the culprit in one of those two places.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse. I'll run through those and let you know on the outcome.

Comment: I've just been through all the .ini files that are loaded in the additional section of `phpinfo()`, and have also run a search through all the files for `ini_set()`. Unfortunately neither of these were the problem.

Comment: That's all I've got then. For me, it has always been one of those two places.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of the PHP application complaining about the upload file size. Using the command lilne version of php (php --ini)I determined the php.ini file to be:
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini

with php -info I verified the settings. but still the application gave me the same error. The I discovered that PHP has different ini files for CLI and Apache. Check your /etc/php5 folder it has apache2 and cli folders with seperate ini files inside. Just edit /etc/php5/cli/php.ini to change the apache settings.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your web server. That's all you need to do.

Comment: As stated in my answer: there were additional config files, which I was unaware of, which were overriding the main config file.

Answer (score 0):

> Bear in mind, I am no sysadmin, I am just a developer. I cannot find anyone with the exact problem as me, just similar, and none of their "fixes" seem to work.

I was in the same boat, with the same problem and turns out they were related!

I had included lines to increase `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` but these were being ignored and `phpinfo()` was returning the default values. I had restarted Apache, and also checked the additional `.ini` files being loaded with no joy.

The solution was that I had added my lines to increase these parameters near the beginning of the file, and they were being overwritten later on in the same file!

So, if you're having this problem, make sure you're not making the same stupid mistake I was, and `Ctrl-F` to find the original instance of the declaration, and then edit that rather than adding your own ;)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what has been noted here already: On Ubuntu 16.04 I did `systemctl reload php7.0-fpm` for my change to `upload_max_filesize` to come into effect. I did not have to reload/restart nginx.

(php7.0 was the current version of PHP installed on my machine.)